# Unity Edge Climb Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

After the climb animation ends, move the transform.position of gameobject to the new position is the advice from experts after thorough research. But there is still a flick issue https://youtu.be/BrI8tElpEag

tried with coroutine to transform.position after animation ends fail so
now transform.position on Animator.OnStateExit() of climbing animation..

still problem persist..

https://github.com/blcx/3D_SideScroller.git

root motion is not an option because , mixamo root bone is on the hip, and unity expect root bone on the floor.

Question is how to smoothly transition to the new position after a bake climb animation ends ?

Comment: Animation depends on many different things. What settings of transition are you set for this animation? The best way to fix this problem - set transition time to 0 and then set the position of player.